# How to use constructor parameter in initializing block

Tags: java, swing

I am using NetBeans IDE for swings programming

This is a Add/Edit scenario, `MyFrame1` handles `MyClass1` obj and `MyClass1` has `MyClass2`, if a `MyClass2` has to be add/edit present in `MyClass1`  `MyFrame1` launches `MyFrame2`

I tried using the following code and got `NullPointerException`

```
class MyFrame2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
  MyFrame1 parent;
  MyClass2 obj;
  Test(MyFrame1 parent){ // For Add scenario
     //this.parent = parent
     obj = new MyClass2();
     //do something
  }
  Test(MyFrame1 parent, MyClass2 obj){ // For Edit scenario
     //this.parent = parent 
     this.obj = obj;
     //do something
  }
  //functions
  ........
  private void foo(){
     parent.addValues(obj); //throws NullPointerException
  }

  //some editor managed code and fields
  ............

  {
     this.parent = parent; 
     //other initalizations
  }
}
```

As far as I know the

1. initializing block code is copied to the beginning of every constructor
2. initializing a field inside initializing block, the declaration of the field should present before the initializing block.

Then why I am getting `NullPointerException` when I include `this.parent = parent;` in  initializing block and works fine if directly added to the constructors?

Is initializing block code not copied to the constructor?

Comment: cant see anywhere in `MyFrame2` an assignment on `this.parent` , except of the initializing block , which will be definitely null , so when you uncomment it from the constructor , it will work fine

Comment: `class MyFrame2 extends JFrame` That seems less than optimal on 2 counts: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) Prefer composition over inheritance when it comes to frames and panels.

Comment: remove the commented lines inside your constructor `this.parent = parent;`

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks for the link and I could use more of that kind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initializing a parent with null.

This

```
 {
     this.parent = parent; 
     //other initalizations
 }
```

is the same as

```
 MyFrame1 parent = null;
```

Comment: So parameters of the constructors cannot be used in Initializing block?

Comment: @Say No, that's not the purpose of these blocks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you are calling the foo method before you call any of the Test methods, at that point obj would have no reference (would be null), causing the NullPointerException, may I suggest making the "Test" methods constructors to avoid this? they seem to serve the porpouse of initializing values anyway

Answer (score 0):

What you are calling initializing block is in really an static initializing block that is called before the constructor and before an instance of MyFrame2 is created.

Learn about static initializing blocks here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html